# Создать массив и добавить в него другие массивы

Tags: java

У меня есть массив. Нужно добавить в него несколько других массивов, чтобы получить конструкцию вида:

```
char[] name = {{'А','Б'},{'В','Г'}}
```

Но писать эту строчку кода не вариант. Массив уже есть в него нужно добавить массивы.Как это сделать и должно ли там быть "[]" или "[][]"? Заранее благодарствую.

Comment: если размер массива уже известен, то можно создать например массив `char[][] arrays = new char[4][2]` ну а потом в цикле добовлять элементы

Answer (score 1):

Массив в массиве - это *двумерный* массив. Массив в массиве в массиве - это *трехмерный* массив и т.д. 
Создать двумерный массивы в Java можно конструкцией [ ] [ ]:

```
char[][] array = new char[length_1][length_2];
```

Обход таких массивов идет в *двойном* цикле:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Обращение к элементам, как видно, через двойные квадратные скобки [row][column] ([строка][столбец]).

Comment: Дополню, что так же можно объявить массив где-нибудь в начале класса и инициализировать его уже в конструкторе, таким образом задавая его размеры непосредственно во время создания объекта.

Comment: Хорошо, но как в таком случае добавлять элементы в двух-,трёх- и т.д. -мерные массивв. Так:

Comment: Как и в обычный массив: array[x][y][z]

http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/urok-12-mnogomerny-e-massivy-v-java/
Рекомендую Вам найти какой-нибудь учебник по Java и вкупе с ним заниматься программированием.